# Trying to create breaks in citations

Tags: overleaf, links, page

I am trying to create a citation page and I need to insert long links into the page (A4). However, it is not fitting in and gives me an overfull \hbox error. How can I fit in a link into the entire page? An example link is below.

```
\begin{enumerate}

\item 2015. Sulfuric Acid Safety Data Sheet. [ebook] Rochester, New York: Fischer Scientific, pp.1-7. Available at: https://beta static.fishersci.com/content/dam/fishersci/en\_US/documents/programs/education/regulatory-documents/sds/chemicals/chemicals-s/S25899.pdf [Accessed 29 January 2021].

\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: URLs are a pain to break right. Load `\usepackage{url}` or `\usepackage{hyperref}` and say `\url{https://beta-static.fishersci.com/content/dam/fishersci/en_US/documents/programs/education/regulatory-documents/sds/chemicals/chemicals-s/S25899.pdf}` (note that you do not need to escape the `_`). Hopefully this gives some useful break points. If not, you could try loading the `xurl` package, which allows line breaks everywhere in the URL and not just in places that look good.

Comment: Note that usually manual bibliographies in LaTeX are created with `\begin{thebibliography}{<largest label>} \bibitem{<entry key>} <... entry data ...> \end{thebibliography}` and not with a raw `\begin{enumerate} \item <entry data> \end{enumerate}`. The advantage of `thebibliography` over `enumarate` is that you can use the semantic `\cite` command to cite your references (`\cite{<entry key>}`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `{xurl}` package in preamble `\usepackage{xurl}` and put `\url{link here}`

```
\begin{enumerate}

\item 2015. Sulfuric Acid Safety Data Sheet. [ebook] Rochester, New York: Fischer Scientific, pp.1-7. Available at: \url {https://beta static.fishersci.com/content/dam/fishersci/en\_US/documents/programs/education/regulatory-documents/sds/chemicals/chemicals-s/S25899.pdf} [Accessed 29 January 2021].

\end{enumerate}
```